# Making intra-annual image composites for a series of years in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat

Below is my code to build a time series collection of all ETM+ and OLI Landsat images intersecting my region of interest. Now I want to build an ImageCollection that represents the mean or median of all images within a year for all years. Can you provide an example of how to build intra-annual composites in Earth Engine.

```
var coefficients = {
  itcps: ee.Image.constant([0.0003, 0.0088, 0.0061, 0.0412, 0.0254, 0.0172]).multiply(10000),
  slopes: ee.Image.constant([0.8474, 0.8483, 0.9047, 0.8462, 0.8937, 0.9071]),
};

// Define function to get and rename bands of interest from OLI.
function renameOLI(img) {
  return img.select(
        ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'pixel_qa'],
        ['Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'NIR', 'SWIR1', 'SWIR2', 'pixel_qa']
    );
}

// Define function to get and rename bands of interest from ETM+.
function renameETM(img) {
  return img.select(
        ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7', 'pixel_qa'],
        ['Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'NIR', 'SWIR1', 'SWIR2', 'pixel_qa']
  );
}

// Define function to apply harmonization transformation.
function etm2oli(img) {
  return img.select(['Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'NIR', 'SWIR1', 'SWIR2'])
    .multiply(coefficients.slopes)
    .add(coefficients.itcps)
    .round()
    .toShort()
    .addBands(img.select('pixel_qa')
    .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start'])
  );
}

// Define function to mask out clouds and cloud shadows.
function fmask(img) {
  var cloudShadowBitMask = 1 << 3;
  var cloudsBitMask = 1 << 5;
  var qa = img.select('pixel_qa');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return img.updateMask(mask);
}

// Define function to calculate NDVI.
function calcNdvi(img) {
  return img.normalizedDifference(['NIR', 'Red']).rename('NDVI');

}

// Define function to prepare OLI images.
function prepOLI(img) {
  var orig = img;
  img = renameOLI(img);
  img = fmask(img);
  img = calcNdvi(img);
  return ee.Image(img.copyProperties(orig, orig.propertyNames()));
}

// Define function to prepare ETM+ images.
function prepETM(img) {
  var orig = img;
  img = renameETM(img);
  img = fmask(img);
  img = etm2oli(img);
  img = calcNdvi(img);
  return ee.Image(img.copyProperties(orig, orig.propertyNames()));
}


// Define a point on the study area
  var aoi = ee.Geometry.Point([34.0049766165165,-6.137332241818918]);

// Define AOI on the map.
Map.centerObject(aoi, 10);
Map.addLayer(aoi, {color: 'f8766d'}, 'AOI');
Map.setOptions('HYBRID');

// Get Landsat surface reflectance collections for OLI, ETM+ and TM sensors.
var oliCol = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR');
var etmCol= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR');

// Define a collection filter.
var colFilter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.bounds(aoi),
  ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 365, 'day_of_year'),
  ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 50),
  ee.Filter.lt('GEOMETRIC_RMSE_MODEL', 10),
  ee.Filter.or(
    ee.Filter.eq('IMAGE_QUALITY', 9),
    ee.Filter.eq('IMAGE_QUALITY_OLI', 9)
  )
);

// Filter collections and prepare them for merging.
oliCol = oliCol.filter(colFilter).map(prepOLI);
etmCol= etmCol.filter(colFilter).map(prepETM);


// Merge the collections.
var col = oliCol
  .merge(etmCol);



Export.image.toAsset({image:col, 
description:"collection", 
assetId:"rungwa", 
region:aoi.bounds(), 
scale:10, 
maxPixels:1e13});
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  As it stands I think your question would benefit from being heavily revised to try and make what you are asking clearer.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make an `ee.List` of years that you want to make intra-annual composites for.
2. Map a compositing function over the list of years. Use each year passed to the function as the start and end time inputs to the `ee.Filter.calendarRange` filter to limit the merged collection to images within a given year. Reduce the resulting intra-annual collection.

Add the following snippet to your script after the merged collection is defined:

```js
// #######################################################################
// ### USER INPUT ###
// #######################################################################

// Define start and end years.
var startYear = 2000;
var endYear = 2019;

// Define a reducer.
var myReducer = ee.Reducer.mean();

// #######################################################################

// Make a list of years to generate composites for.
var yearList = ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear);

// Map over the list of years to generate a composite for each year - returns an List.
var yearCompList = yearList.map(function(year){
  // Filter the merged collection by the given year.  
  var yearCol = col.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'));
  // Make a list of filtered images for this year as a record.
  var imgList = yearCol.aggregate_array('LANDSAT_ID');
  // Reduce (composite) the images for this year.
  var yearComp = yearCol.reduce(myReducer);
  // Count the number of bands (used as a filter in a following step).
  var nBands = yearComp.bandNames().size();
  // Return the intra-annual composite - set properties just defined.
  return yearComp.set({
    'year': year,
    'image_list': imgList,
    'n_bands': nBands
  });
});

// Convert the annual composite image List to an ImageCollection
var yearCompCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(yearCompList);

// Filter out years with no bands.
//(can happen if there were no images to composite)
yearCompCol = yearCompCol.filter(ee.Filter.gt('n_bands', 0));

// Check the work using year 2015. Filter year 2015.
var year2015 = yearCompCol.filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', 2015)).first();
// Get the list of images used to make the 2015 composite.
var imgList = year2015.get('image_list');
// Print the image list.
print('Images composited:', imgList);
// Display 2015 NDVI mean composite to the Map. 
Map.addLayer(year2015, {bands: ['NDVI_mean'], min: 0.2, max: 0.7, 
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ]}
);
```

Here is the entire script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/f8fd2c51107d2663c3f308efbf046c06

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked  very well.but I need to go further to make each year a band in this collection from 2000 to 2019, so that ultimately my collection is made of 20 bands. how can I do this?

Comment: Use the `toBands()` ImageCollection method. If you get stuck, ask a separate question on it.